# Empty database in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database

What is the best way to test for an empty database in rails? I generated a model chardata and the controller, Chardatum. I want to loop through the database and extract a certain column, but I need a way to test if the database is empty first.

Comment: First of all: I think your model should be singular (CharDatum) and your Controller plural (CharData).
And I assume you mean that you want to check if the table char_data is empty, instead of the whole database?

Comment: Empty meaning a table with no records? or meaning a database with no tables?

Answer (score 2):

If you are fetching some Chardata allready you could do:

```
@chardata.any?
```

Comment: You don't have to fetch them first. This is also possible: `CharData.any?`.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on two things.

What kind of database are you using?
And by empty, do you mean the tables have not been created yet? or just that data has not been inserted yet in to the tables?

To see if the chardatas table has no rows before proceeding:

```
Chardata.count.zero?
```

Assuming you're using MySQL, you can use the following command to see if tables have been created already in your database

```
Chardata.count_by_sql "SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT 'table_name') FROM 'information_schema'.'columns' WHERE 'table_schema' = 'your_db_name'".zero?
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also check if the table has been created with `CharDatum.table_exists?`.